# Windows batch: unable to filter out the exactly matching line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am using this command to filter out the line `set timing on;`

```
type filea.sql | findstr /v "^set timing on;$"
```

and the output,I'm getting is as follows:

```
whenever sqlerror exit 9;

grant select on exfdsfds;


exit;
```

The content of filea.sql is:

```
set timing on;
whenever sqlerror exit 9;

grant select on exfdsfds;

timing on; cool

exit;
```

Why is it removing `timing on; cool`?What modifications to command are needed to avoid such results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented in `findstr /?` you need to use `/c` if you want to match a whole string containing spaces:

> Use spaces to separate multiple search strings unless the argument is prefixed with /C.  For example, 'FINDSTR "hello there" x.y' searches for "hello" or "there" in file x.y.  'FINDSTR /C:"hello there" x.y' searches for "hello there" in file x.y.

If you want to use `^` and `$` you also need `/r`, otherwise the string will be treated as a literal string instead of a regular expression.

```
type filea.sql | findstr /v /r /c:"^set timing on;$"
```

Without `/c` the command removes all lines containing any of the given words from the output, which includes the line `timing on; cool` because there's a match for the word `timing`.